# Why does SageMaker PyTorch DDP init times out on SageMaker?

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, distributed-training, amz-sagemaker-distributed-training

I'm using PyTorch DDP on SageMaker PyTorch Training DLC 1.8.1 The code seems properly DDP-formatted. I'm using instance_count = 2, and launching `torch.distributed.launch` and I believe the ranks and world size are properly set however the `dist.init_process_group` waits and times out

```
RuntimeError: Timed out initializing process group in store based barrier on rank: 0, for key: store_based_barrier_key:1 (world_size=2, worker_count=1, timeout=0:30:00)
```

What could go wrong? machines not networked together?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually something to do with the way local_rank is retrieved and used during initialization. Please refer to the below example and see if you can figure out the difference.

https://github.com/aruncs2005/pytorch-ddp-sagemaker-example

Answer (score 0):

The **torch.distributed.launch** is the helper utility within the *torch.distributed* package which can be used to launch multiple processes per node for distributed training. It tells all workers which IP address is of rank 0 which is set by MASTER_ADDR,

Each rank needs to be able to communicate to the *MASTER_ADDR* on the port *MASTER_PORT*. If those are set but the workers cannot reach the MASTER_ADDR, then it can be the root cause of hang and timeoutfor the job.

Besides, it will also wait until all nodes report in from *--nodes* defined in the launch as well.